# Generate Barcode

Tags: c#, qr-code, barcode

```
QRCode barcode = new QRCode();
barcode.Code = "QR Code";
barcode.Format = ImageFormat.Gif;
barcode.drawBarcode2ImageFile("c:/qr-code-csharp.gif")
```

Can someone explain me each above lines of code for generating QR code.What does it actually meant by barcode.drawBarcode2ImageFile("c:/qr-code-csharp.gif")

Answer (score 0):

```
...
barcode.Code = "QR Code"; // Content that will be encoded into qr code
barcode.Format = ImageFormat.Gif; // Image format of qr code
barcode.drawBarcode2ImageFile("c:/qr-code-csharp.gif"); // Path/directory in your pc to save image that has qr code
```

Comment: Usually it is a good idea to expound on the code in your answer. Tell about how it works or what exactly you are doing. This helps newer developers understand exactly what is going on.